# Fragment layout not showing after ViewPager kills it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Right now I am using Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator library.  I have added several `Fragments` into it and can swipe back and forth fine.  If I swipe more than one panel away from a `Fragment`, then it gets removed (`onDestroyView()` called).  Conversely, if I swipe within one panel from a `Fragment`, then it gets added back (`onCreateView()` called).

When my `Fragment` is destroyed/added back again, the `Views` that were once present in it are destroyed and I come back to a blank screen.  I have a `LinearLayout` in my `Fragment` that I add `TextViews` to.  Calling `.size()` on the `LinearLayout` when it is recreated shows that the correct count, but I can't figure out what to call in order to get it displayed again.  I've tried adding `<LinearLayout>.requestLayout()` in `onResume()`, but that didn't work.

Let me know if I should post any relevant code.  I don't think any of this is really specific to my Fragment however.

**edit**: So originally I was thinking that I would have to deal with `onSavedInstanceState()`, but I've never saved an entire layout in that before.  Another idea I had was to iterate my `LinkedList` of `TextViews` and then add them back to my `LinearLayout`.  This gave me an error with the `View` already having a parent, which makes sense.

Here is how I add my TextView:

```
public void addQuickLook(QuickLookView v)
{
    mViews2.add(v); //LinkedList of QuickLookViews
    mMeterLayout.addView(v); //Adding to the LinearLayout
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quicklook, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mMeterLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.quickLookList);
}
```

Comment: can you post one of the fragments that doesn't work?  the problem is most likely with where you adding your textviews

Comment: This is a question on `ViewPager` which is part of the support library and not ViewPagerIndicator itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've solved this.  What I did was overrided the `destroyItem()` method in my `FragmentPagerAdapter` and left it blank.  I should have read the developer's page for `FragmentPagerAdapter` more closely to see its expected behavior, particularly that everything is loaded into memory and it kills the Views of a `Fragment` to save memory when it isn't visible anymore.  Not sure if this is the right approach, but it works fine for now.